# Find a jquery object inside a javascript <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script in an HTML page of the following:

```
<script id="scriptid" type="text/html">
    <div id="insidedivid">
        ... html code ...
    </div>
</script>
```

I am able to get the `HTMLScriptElement` using `$("#scriptid")` but I am not able to get the underlying div object with the id `"insidedivid"`. Whats the way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to do something with templating? http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: @undefined: When using libraries like `knockoutJs` or `Handlebars` for example that is how you have to define the templates.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, you are right man, but I don't think this question is related to those libraries.

Comment: @undefined: I mentioned the libraries as an example only of why one might add html in-between script tags not because I think OP uses them.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible; the browser does not treat HTML content inside of `<script>` tags as part of the DOM. When you retrieve the content of the `<script>` tag with `$('#idhere').html()`, you're getting a string result.

To answer Troy's question, he's most likely including templates in the `<head>` of his document so he can ultimately render content dynamically on the browser-side. However, if that is the case, the OP should use a different MIME type than `text/html`. You should use an unknown MIME type such as `text/templates`--using `text/html` confuses what the purpose of the content is.

I'm **guessing** the reason you're trying to reach into the `<script>` tag and grab a `div` is because you've built smaller sub-templates within the single `<script>` tag. Those smaller templates should rather be placed into their own `<script></script>` tags rather than contained in one large `<script></script>` tag pair.

So, instead of:

```
<script type="text/template" id="big_template">
    <div id="sub_template_1">
        <span>hello world 1!</span>
    </div>
    <div id="sub_template_2">
        <span>hello world 2!</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Do this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template_1">
    <span>hello world 1!</span>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="template_2">
    <span>hello world 2!</span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly valid to have a div inside a script tag (or at
least useful), if a div makes sense to the TYPE you defined for the
script. For example, John Resig uses a script tag with type "text/
html" in his micro-templating solution:
http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/
In this instance though (and in reply to the original author) you add
an ID to the SCRIPT tag, and refer to that (I don't see why it
wouldn't work with that facebook type instead of html - but you'd
probably want to test it in a few different browsers ;). For the
example you gave, you can get a reference to the DIV by doing:

```
<script id="scriptid" type="text/html">
    <div id="insidedivid">
        ... html code ...
    </div>
</script>
    $(function(){
        alert($( $( '#scriptid' ).html() ).text() ); //alerts " ... html code ..."
    });
```

The "trick" is to get the HTML of the script tag and turn in into DOM
elements with jQuery - but remember, because you are passing all the
HTML into the jQUery function then you are immediately selecting ALL
of the top level elements. In this case, there is just one DIV - so
you are just selecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org).

If you want to have HTML you can get just like that, use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var msg1 = $('message1');
    // Execute code here
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="hidden" style="display: none">
        <div id="message1">Message 1</div>
        <div id="message2">Message 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are making a templating system, you may want to use AJAX instead.